# Is there any way to place two UISearchBar in UITableView?

Tags: objective-c, uisearchbar

I have a UITableView with customized UITableViewCells, now i have already placed one UISearchBar to find one of the data in UITableViewCell and it is working fine.

Now i want to do search operation for the other data which is placed in UITableViewCell, so is there a way to place another UISearchBar programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It's totally flexible. You just need to create the cell and you can control the placement using the UITableViewDataSource/Delegate methods.